# From Rotman "Introduction to the Theory of Groups", Proof of Hall Theorem 5.28, Why do Q char K follows from K=HQ, Page 109

Tags: group-theory

At the end of the Existence Proof, Rotman says that Q char K follows from K=HQ.Can anyone explain why this is true?